# how can i find specific values in multiple columns and then in another column show the column name where that specific value is found

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
ID    Assignment    Sex   Age_0_34   Age_35_45
1      MBT           F    0%          0%
1      MBT           F    0%          0%
2      MBT           F    0%          2.5%
2      MBT           F    0%          0%
3      MBT           F    1.5%        0%
3      MBT           F    0%          0%
4      MBT           F    0%          0%
4      MBT           F    0%          1.2%
```

[image]

What I want to have after the last column is like this:

```
ID    Assignment    Sex   Age_0_34   Age_35_45   Age
1      MBT           F    2.0%        0%         Age_0_34
1      MBT           F    0%          5.0%       Age_35_45
2      MBT           F    0%          2.5%       Age_35_45
2      MBT           F    0%          0%         0         
3      MBT           F    1.5%        0%         Age_0_34
3      MBT           F    0%          0%         0
4      MBT           F    3.5%        0%         Age_0_34
4      MBT           F    0%          1.2%       Age_35_45
```

[image]

So basically what I am trying to do is to create a column which has a value greater than 1% and show the column name in last column age next to that row

Comment: What is the algorithm for the differences in `[Age_0_34]:[Age_35_45]` columns from your  original data to that which shows in you desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function for this:

[image]

Use this formula in your new column (adjust references appropriately):

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($K$1:$L$1,$K2:$L2>0),0)
```

You may want to change the zero at the end to an empty string, i.e.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($K$1:$L$1,$K2:$L2>0),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your initial data set is in error, with regard to the two age columns, you can use the following formula:

```
M2: =IFERROR(INDEX($H$1:$L$1,3+ MATCH(TRUE,$K2:$L2>=1%,0)),0)
```

and fill down as far as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(D2=0,E2=0),0,IF(D2>E2,$D$1,$E$1))
```

[image]